# PhpMyAdmin for Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know of a similar tool as phpmyadmin for sqlserver ? Especially the data dump is very handy. But also updating etc, without needing to remotely logon etc. is nice.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's the new Database Manager application:

http://www.iis.net/extensions/databasemanager

At Mix 2009, Microsoft announced this and demoed it.  I haven't used it myself, but the demos were gorgeous, and since it's maintained by Microsoft, it's probably the safest bet.

Comment: Looks good ! I'll check it out.

Comment: This is built-in to IIS, unlike the web-based interface of phpMyAdmin, right?

Comment: No, that's something you have to add - it's pretty similar to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

Weird that no one mentionned [myLittleAdmin](http://mylittleadmin.com).
This is a 13-year-old project with a robust and stable kernel. Its interface is very similar to SSMS one. And of course it is a full web-based app.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Web Data Administrator](http://www.codeplex.com/SqlWebAdmin) may be sufficient for what you're looking to do, but it hasn't been updated in about a year and a half. If you need more info, [there's a review by SQL Server MVP Jacob Sebastian on SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Product+Reviews/3025/).

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly looked for one and haven't found anything decent.  However, [Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/) recently said he is going to try to build one for the [European WinPHP Challenge 2009](http://wiki.phpconference.nl/2009_WinPHP_Challenge), so it might be worth watching.

http://akrabat.com/2009/04/29/the-eurowinphp-application/