# Equivalent of phpMyAdmin for MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, web-applications, remote-access

Is there any webinterface for administrating MSSQL similar to phpMyAdmin (for MySQL)?

I want a self-service setup where developers can create a database through webinterface and upload/download backups of the database without local access.

I've considered [phpMSAdmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmsadmin/files/phpmsadmin/), but it hasn't had a release since 2006 so I'm not sure its worth the effort of setting it up. If there is something else (free or not-so-free) that would be great.

My question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/485/phpmyadmin-for-sql-server) posted 2 years ago, but no good webinterface was found back then. [SQL Web Data Administrator](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/) seems interesting, but it lacks a few features - most notably creating new databases (also, not updated since 2007).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [MyLittleAdmin](http://www.mylittleadmin.com) that we use. I find it strange that it's not been mentioned here. We've used it for years and I think our developers find it works well for them. I think it's crazy that there's not a official web based tool like phpMyadmin for MSSQL. I don't want to give our developers access to our production SQL Servers so a web based solution is ideal for us.

Comment: Sir, Thank You! As you see my question was from almost 1,5 years agso, and it mentions that it was a re-post of a question from 2 years before that. I had given up and settled with Management Studio.

Answer (score 4):

There's no default web interface like phpMyAdmin.  Typically you wouldn't want to expose your Microsoft SQL Servers to the public net.  You would normally connect via VPN then use SQL Server Management Studio to connect.

The web interfaces that you found will probably do the trick, but without providing access to some of the newer features.  If you are just looking for basic functionality those will work just fine.  The nice thing about SQL Server is that anything you can do in SSMS you can do in T/SQL so if the web interface you have doesn't provide functionality you can still manage and use those features using T/SQL.

Comment: The exact same applies to MySQL - you don't want to expose 3306, and you can do everything in SQL commands. I can name several reasons why webinterface with proper login system is better than opening 1433 directly. But thats not the issue here, the server is protected behind FW+VPN anyway. What I want is a self-service webinterface, specifically for uploading/downloading backups and creating new DB's. phpMyAdmin is a perfect example.

Comment: Btw! For those of us that had the pleasure of reinstalling customer servers after the MSSQL worms that roamed in the early 2k we NEVER expose MSSQL-ports to the net. ;)

Comment: I try not to expose any management tools to be accessable via the net, including any sort of web interface.  If I need to manage a server I VPN in.  If VPN isn't an option I RDP to a server on the network and use SSMS from there.  Microsoft is always adding features to SQL Server, keeping a 3rd party web tool up to date would be tough to say the least for a company.

Comment: If it is on a network, it is exposed to the net... just saying.

Answer (score 1):

*NOT EQUIVALENT OF PHPMYADMIN, BUT I'M USING PHPMYADMIN + HEIDISQL TOGETHER FOR MYSQL AND HEIDISQL SUPPORTS MS-SQL TOO*

As a developer coming from the MySQL, having to use MS-SQL for enterprise projects, I was surprised to see that HeidiSQL that was using for MySQL worked for MS-SQL databases too. HeidiSQL is free (I promise you when you'll use it, you'd really want to donate in the end, it's amazing), and it supports many database types and connections. One thing though is that sometimes you get some weird problems when altering tables/columns, other than that you get to keep the amazing filtering, browsing, multi-editing features that you have on other database systems.

Comment: I just downloaded this and it blows Server Management Studio out of the water!

Answer (score 0):

As mrdenny says, there is no default web interface for mssql. And I rather not use third party program that hasn't released update since more than 3 years... pretty dangerous if the security isn't improved.

As form me, I use [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/features.html)
 for my database managing. It's a good tool, you just have to create a connection (ip, port, databasename, and so on...) And you can interact with your database, you can do almost anything (if you're connected as root), a very complete tool. But it's not as friendly as phpmyadmin, but still better (well, at least for me.)

Give it a try.

Comment: But then I can just as well use Management Studio? I need a webinterface.

Comment: Using Web interface is good only if you work on the server intranet (at some peculiar time only!). If you want to work on you database with a security point of view, web interface is not really what you need. 

Also if I recall good (not use it everyday), but you can't access database with management studio when you not on the server intranet. But you can easily with razosql.

As for web interface applet for database managing, once I used mylittleadmin. As far as I recall, was a good web interface. Try it, and see if it's what you were looking for. ;)

Comment: There is no good web interface apparently, thanks for the RazorSQL just installed and managed to get decent csv and xlsexport from MSSQL!

Comment: good to know. ^^